# Android : URI for open an image with ACTION View

Tags: android, actionview

This is the code

```
protected static final String DIR_IMAGE = "/data/data/it.android.myprogram/images/";
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
Uri u = Uri.fromFile(destinationFile);
intent.setDataAndType(u, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

the file to open is into /data/data/it.android.myprogram/images if I do :

```
File dir = new File(DIR_IMAGE);
String[] files = dir.list();
```

The var files contain all files but when I start

```
intent.setDataAndType(u, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

It dispaly the message Impossible to find /data/data/it.android.myprogram/images/img1.jpg

Why ??

Answer (score 6):

Files in `/data/data/it.android.myprogram` are only accessible by your application. If you want to send them via Intent to others applications, you must copy content in using `openFileOutput` method of your activity.

```
protected static final String DIR_IMAGE = "/data/data/it.android.myprogram/images/";
String filePath = DIR_IMAGE + "fileName";
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("fileName", Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
ByteStreams.copy(fileInputStream, fileOutputStream);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://it.android.myprogram/fileName"), "image/*");
```

Hope it helps