# How to open a file in Android via an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, filesystems, actionview

how can I open a file that has been previously stored in the "privat" filesystem? The file is being downloaded by a webservice and should be stored on local fs.
I got a "strange" error when trying to open the file via an Intent (Action_View). Although the file is present in the filesystem (saw the file in the file explorer in emulator/eclipse) it won't be shown in the calling galery activity that is launched. Instead of the picture the galery shows a black screen with not content in there (except the action bar). The same occurs when trying to open a pdf/movie/mp3 file via this method (pdf says for example that the file is corrupt).

BTW: The data that has been stored on the local fs is valid (not corrupt), I downloaded the files from debugger (via pull method) and the files can be opened on my workstation...

```
public void onAttachment(Context context, Attachment attachment) {
    try {
        //Attachment is a structured data object that contains of a byte[], filename and mimetype (like image/jpeg)
        FileOutputStream fos = FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(attachment.getAttachmentFileName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(attachment.getBinary());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        File f = context.getFileStreamPath(attachment.getAttachmentFileName());
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);          
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri,attachment.getAttachmentMimetype());
        context.startActivity(intent);                  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068648/launching-an-intent-for-file-and-mime-type/11088980#11088980 can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the location to "`openFileOutput("fileName", Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE)`" it will work. Other apps cannot read the data (even for viewing) stored when setting to "`Context.MODE_PRIVATE`"

see [other post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399001/android-uri-for-open-an-image-with-action-view)

Answer (score 12):

What is the type of the Attachment in your code? Perhaps it returns wrong mime type?

This code works for me:

```
File file = new File("EXAMPLE.JPG");

// Just example, you should parse file name for extension
String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(".JPG");

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mime);
startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

Comment: No, this won't work... The problem is that the activity is successfully being launched (galery, movie-/audio player, pdf-reader) but the content (file) seems invalid...

Comment: The attachment returns the correct mimetype, otherwise the correct activity (Galery/Mediaplayer/PDF-Reader) wouldn't be started at all.

Comment: Wrong. The parameter of getMimeTypeFromExtension MUST be a file extension without the leading '.'.

Comment: that worked for me. I was calling `Uri.parse(file.getPath())` instead of `Uri.fromFile(file)`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot open files that are not on the sdcard like that.
You'll need to copy the file to the sdcard and then opening it.

Comment: Can you give me a link where this is confirmed by google (in sdk documentation). I didn't find anything about that in the official documentation... 
BTW: When I open the file in an own activity that can handle images it works...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm talking out of experience so I don't have a link. BUT its the same problem as in uploading or emailing a file that's no in the SDCARD... Its the same with opening webview pages & etc.. Hope it helps... Sorry if not..

Comment: So I have to write own Viewer-"Activities" that can handle the files that are stored on this private folder?

Comment: Or just copy them to a private folder on the SDCARD, and if you want delete them after.
Private (actually invisible )folder on SDCARD: 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.priavte_dir"

Comment: But the files will be accessible (by another application, for example a filebrowser-app) after that... Also you have you have to imply that the user has a sd-card and it must be mounted too. Hm...