# How to open a jpg resource using a button within activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to open a jpg file from res/raw folder using a button in the activity.  However when launching and testing the app I get an error saying:

```
11-09 10:20:51.654: E/AndroidRuntime(3247): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///android.resource:/com.image.imagetest/2131034112 typ=application/jpg flg=0x4000000 }`
```

This is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);

    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Image1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(final View v) {

            File jpgFile = new File("android.resource://com.image.imagetest/" + R.raw.mainimage);
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(jpgFile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/jpg");

            startActivity(intent);    

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Am I missing something here :-) ?

**EDIT**

I have now done this but now when launching app to test i get a message saying "unable to find item" from clicking the button.  Here is my code:

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
    File jpgFile = new File("android.resource://com.image.imagetest/" + R.raw.mainimage);
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(jpgFile);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "image/jpeg");
    startActivity(intent);  
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585747/how-to-open-a-file-in-android-via-an-intent

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `file:/` when creating `intent` :

```
File jpgFile = new File("file:/android.resource://com.image.imagetest/" + R.raw.mainimage);
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(jpgFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

Take a look here : [No Activity found to handle Intent : android.intent.action.VIEW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882656/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-android-intent-action-view)

Comment: Thanks, but am still getting the same error.  I have tried the link given above aswell but still giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use a `File` here. Just put the Uri in the Intent :

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.image.imagetest/" + R.raw.mainimage));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);    
  }
```

What's wrong with your solution ?

- too complex (no need to use a File)
- the mimetype is wrong : use `image/jpeg` instead of `application/jpg`

Comment: Thank you, but have edited my qeustion,  it seems now that it can't locate the item/file i think.

Comment: [Stackoverflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum/#92110) : one precise question --> answers. If you are stuck with another problem : ask another question and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [this](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) before posting