# Can't launch intent to show local image

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin

Within my fragment, I am trying to start an intent to display a local image with a gallery app on my phone.

The three lines in question are

```
string path = String.Format ("content:/{0}.jpg", CacheController.Static.GetPath (m));
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
StartActivity (new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri));
```

the value of path is `content://data/data/Appname.subname/files/cache/107.jpg`.

I tried using `file:/` at the beginning of the `Uri` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to share an image that is in a folder private to your app. You first need to copy the image to a public folder and make an intent pointing to that image. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399001/android-uri-for-open-an-image-with-action-view)